# How to query using a field from the first related object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In a view, I have the a parameter called `keyword`. What I'm trying to do is query the `User` table for any users that contain the `keyword` in either the `username` field **OR** `display_name` field, **AND** also the first related profile's `name` field. Hopefully that makes sense. Is there a way to do this in one single query? Some users may not have any profiles, so that also needs to be accounted for.

So far, I've got this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_queryset(keyword):
    qs = User.objects.all()
    qs = qs.filter(Q(username__icontains=keyword), Q(display_name__icontains=keyword))
    return qs
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please add your own query and we continue from that? Also do you want to include users that doesn't have a profile?

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın Just added

Comment: Can user have a multiple profiles? Do you want to include users that has no profile to the query result? Can you elaborate the `first related profile's name field`? Sorry I didn't get that part

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın Yep, users can have multiple profiles, but only the first (default sort) needs to be queried. And yeah, I want to include users without any profiles too.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this and it'll probably won't work at first run but might be a good starting point. I'm not sure about the performance either but can you let me know when you try this and I can fix the code. It'd be nice to have a minimal reproducible example for this though.

```
from django.db.models import Q, OuterRef, Subquery

def get_queryset(keyword):
    first_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=OuterRef('id'))
    qs = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=keyword) | Q(display_name__icontains=keyword)).annotate(first_profile_name=Subquery(first_profile.values('name')[:1])).filter(Q(first_profile_name=None) | Q(first_profile_name__icontains=keyword))
    return qs
```

Comment: Nope, returns an empty queryset

Comment: Maybe I get it wrong. This query will return user instances that contain the keyword in username or displayname. In addition to that, if there's not a profile instance, it'll include the user. If there's a profile instance, it'll check the first profile's name and it should ALSO contain the keyword. Is that right? Having a match on the user's username or displayname is a MUST as I understand. 
Can you please make sure such a record exists? (Please be careful about using icontains instead of contains for disabling the case sensitivity)

Comment: Can you create users that has no profile, has a single profile, has multiple profiles (that matches the keyword with first profile, and matches the keyword with second profile) to test out the various scenarios. Maybe order of the first_profile query is wrong, so you should include order_by to that query.

Comment: Yes to all possibilities of profiles, not sure what you mean by the `order_by` to be honest. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: If you get no result, problem is not the order. I've tried this query on my database and it returns result. Can you create a simple project with sample data and table, so I can test it on my local? I can't see the problem here, sorry.

Comment: Let me try that again, sorry I may have missed something before because I changed the field names to ask the question.